# How to change the align of button navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 and trying to align the button on a navbar when it is collapsed. I wanna that button stay on left but it is always on right.

How could I do this ?

**Trying**

```
<div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="pull-left navbar-toggle custom-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" style="border-color:yellow;">
                <span class="sr-only">Menu</span>
                <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color:yellow;"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color:yellow;"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color:yellow;"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")" class="navbar-brand"><img class="img-responsive" width="150" height="50" src="~/Imagens/logo1.png" style="margin-top:1.5px" /></a>
            @*@Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })*@
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">            
             <ul>
                <li>Option 1</li>
                <li>Option 2</li>
             </ul>        
        </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use Bootstrap3 classes `pull-left` and `pull-right` to move your toggle to left and logo to right.
2. You can use CSS with `float:left` property for the `navbar-toggle`. That will move your toggle button to left.

```
.navbar-toggle {
  float: left !important;
}
```

Here is the working snippet for the same using Bootstrap classes

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Welcome</title>
</head>

<body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand pull-right href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pricing">PRICING</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>

</html>
```